# cannot implicitly convert decimal for one category

Tags: c#

I am writing code that will allow my employees information to be displayed on a web browser. Everything is going well except at the part of employee salary. It is a decimal value. So what do I do so that I can fix the error, which says cannot implicitly convert decimal ?

```
EmpDBEntities6 dc;
public ftempservice()
{
    dc = new EmpDBEntities6();
}

public List<ftEmpInfo> GetAllEmployee()
{
    var query = (from a in dc.FRYEMPs select a).Distinct();
    List<ftEmpInfo> EmployeeList = new List<ftEmpInfo>();
    query.ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        EmployeeList.Add(new ftEmpInfo
        {
            EmployeeID = Convert.ToString(x.EmployeeID),
            EmployeeName = x.EmployeeName,
            EmployeePosition = x.EmployeePosition,
            EmployeeSalary = x.EmployeeSalary,
        });
    });
    return EmployeeList;
}

public ftEmpInfo EmployeeDetails(string employeeID)
{
    ftEmpInfo Emp = new ftEmpInfo();
    try
    {
        var query = (from a in dc.FRYEMPs
                     where a.EmployeeID.Equals(employeeID)
                     select a).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
        Emp.EmployeeID = query.EmployeeID;
        Emp.EmployeeName = query.EmployeeName;
        Emp.EmployeePosition = query.EmployeePosition;
        Emp.EmployeeSalary = query.EmployeeSalary;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new FaultException<string>(ex.Message);
    }
    return Emp;
}
```

Here is ftEmpInfo

```
[DataContract]
public class ftEmpInfo
{
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeePosition { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSalary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: also show the ftEmpInfo.cs model

Comment: Which line is giving the error? And you need to show the definition of the classes in question ftEmpInfo and whatever a single FRYEMPs looks like

Comment: error would say  cannot implicitly convert decimal ** to something** why not put the entire exception... that would help you not get -vly voted

Comment: Which line gives the error? What is the datatype of `EmployeeSalary`? Is it decimal or `decimal?` ? The error message you shared is not complete. Can you share the complete message of the exception?

Comment: Change `ftEmpInfo.EmployeeSalary`'s type from `string` to `decimal`? If you can't do that then call `query.EmployeeSalary.ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your salary is string..you could convert your salary to String to supress the error **ToString**

```
var query = (from a in dc.FRYEMPs
                     where a.EmployeeID.Equals(employeeID)
                     select a).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
        Emp.EmployeeID = query.EmployeeID;
        Emp.EmployeeName = query.EmployeeName;
        Emp.EmployeePosition = query.EmployeePosition;
        Emp.EmployeeSalary = query.EmployeeSalary.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: It's `ToString`, not `toString`

Comment: yup  next time put exception as it is..dont shortcut it..its the only piece of info that is helpful

Comment: add better models...we know EmployeeID  will always be Int why keep it as string...waali bhai vote to kero

Comment: @RohitasBehera employee ID is not always numeric,